# What does "*" mean in [*generator] in python?

Tags: python

I got a generator `g`, I can use `list(g)` or `[*g]` to get a list of the items in `g`. But what does the "*" mean here?

Comment: It means unpacking of values. You can search more on this in Google.

Comment: Unpacking. Originally it used to be allowed only in the function argument, as in the duplicate Q&A shows. But it is allowed in broader contexts such as `[]`, as in your question (since python 3.5). https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Please refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492308/) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166505/) which is found in the linked thread.  More information found in all other answers in the thread.

Comment: The * operator is an unpacking operator that will unpack the values from any iterable object, such as lists, tuples, strings. Please checkout this blog https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480  for detailed information.